# Straight into bios after starting windows 8 on asus zenbook

Tags: grub2, windows-8, bios, mint

I have a strange problem for which I hope anyone here has the answer.

I recently bought a Zenbook prime UX31A. I installed Mint 15 (based on Ubuntu 13.04) after I switched of the secure boot in the BIOS, enabled CSM in the BIOS, disabled fast boot in both Windows 8 and the BIOS. During the installation, I decreased the size of the Windows partition.

Everything worked well, until Windows 8 installed updates. Directly afterwards, I could only get into the BIOS and where the hard disk would not be visible at all. I also flashed the BIOS to the lasted version (219).

It seems that I can kind of fix the problem by a combination of the following steps (it only seems like it, because it doesn't work every time):

1. I restore the default settings in the BIOS.
2. I restart while pressing F9.
3. I hold the power button for >40s.
4. Start-up tells me that it found an unknown signature.
5. I disable the secure boot and fast boot in BIOS
6. I restart
7. GRUB is back, I start the BIOS again and enable CSM (which I am not allowed to do in 5. or some strange reason; I need the restart first

Now I can start Linux again without any problems. However, every time I start windows, I have the same problem. Does anybody have an idea how I can fix that?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately Linux Mint questions are off-topic here ):

Comment: It would be on topic in the [Unix and Linux stack exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). This one is specifically for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many people who have been able to successfully run Windows 8 with Ubuntu, but in my experience having tried several times, every time Windows 8 boots it seems to run some sort of "fix" routine that reclaims the laptop.  I'm sure Microsoft would say it is to help fix boot up problems since most users will never install two OSes.  I say though that it is Microsoft assuming that their OS is the only one in the world, and screw everybody else anyway :-)

On most of the laptops I used, we ended up wiping Win 8 out and installing it into a Virtual Machine.  [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) and [VMWare Player](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/downloads) are both good ones.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Ok then, that's what I am going to do. Thanks.